# React Speedometer percentage value formatting shows too many decimals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-d3-speedometer

I am using react-d3-speedometer to display speedometers on my React web application but I am running into a problem.

I want to use percentages as values for one of the speedometers but all the number in the svg have about 8 decimals by default. It looks like this: [image]

The code I use for this speedometer is as follows:

```
<ReactSpeedometer
                        maxValue={1}
                        value={0.5924}
                        valueFormat="%"
                        width={250}
                        height={150}
                      />
```

I assume that this should not be the default behaviour and that I perhaps set a value wrongly, but I cannot find anyone else with this issue on this website or the developers. I hope one of you lovely Stack Overflow people can come to the rescue. Thanks in advance to anyone that answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from here: https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format :
`If the precision is not specified, it defaults to 6 for all types except ​ (none), which defaults to 12`.

So you should try it with  `.2%` in the `valueFormat` to get 2 digits after the dot.

```
<ReactSpeedometer
                        maxValue={1}
                        value={0.5924}
                        valueFormat=".2%"
                        width={250}
                        height={150}
                      />
```

Edit:
For using different digits i'd go with this

```
function Speedometer() {
    const value = 0.8;
    return (
        <ReactSpeedometer
            maxValue={1}
            value={value}
            valueFormat=".0%"
            width={250}
            height={150}
            currentValueText={`${value * 100}%`}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question if you don't mind, the valueFormat counts for both the value (the text under the speedometer) and the labels above the speedometer segments. This causes the labels above the segments to still be quite big (especially 100.00%). Is there a way to format the value label to have 2 decimals, but the segment labels to have none?

Comment: I added an Edit for this question. By using the backticks in `currentValueTest` you can format the string.